# count number of empty rows an display in cell excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with excel sheet. I tried to solve the problem on my own with a loop in vba but my skills are just to poor.

Task:

A cell in in worksheet 1 should display the number of empty cells between two cells in worsheet 2.

Example:

- there are two entries in workseeht 2 one in A9 (active cell value =543) the next in A15 (active cell value = 35)

  - In worksheet 2 the five cells between A9 and A15 are empty
  - Cell B2 in worksheet 1 should now count the empty cells from A9 until A15 in worksheet 2
  - Cell B2 in workseet 1 should now have the value 5

Context:
I am a student working on a data base and I have to perform the taks described above for several times in the data base. In the database the number of empty cells that need to be counted represent the number of prodcutio plants a company has.

Thank you in advance for the help, I hope I can improve my skills fast so i wont have to bother you anymore

Cheers Leon

Answer (score 2):

In cell B2 on Sheet1, place this formula:

```
=COUNTBLANK(Sheet2!A9:A15)
```